# Does claiming on travel insurance increase your premium for future policies?

Tags: travel-insurance-claim

I am currently fighting Iberia for a lost luggage claim that is taking a huge amount of time and effort. Even though they owe me and should pay out, I'm considering just claiming through my travel insurance instead to make life easier.

The only issues are that I will have to pay an excess and I'm worried that if I use the same company for an annual policy in the future they will increase my premium as happens with for example buildings insurance.

Will this happen or not?

Comment: I do not know how many different insurance companies there are but I am sure many have different rules for this kind of claim.

Comment: travel insurance claim is rarely your fault, and unless you're extremely unlucky to have a reason for a claim for every trip, I doubt anyone would care. I've never been asked for my prior travel insurance history before buying a policy.

Comment: It's unlikely, but as @Willeke says it depends on the insurance company.